# How does Android render Views within a Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having trouble with a (I think) simple LinearLayout. (Long question - sorry) I have an XML layout with a RelativeLayout as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Player_Init"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Player" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_USGA_Index"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/display_Tees"
        android:text="IDX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Course_HCP"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/display_USGA_Index"
        android:text="HCP" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Course"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/display_Player_Init"
        android:text="Course" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Tees"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/display_Course"
        android:text="Tees" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This shows in the IDE preview correctly as follows:

***Crap, not enough rep points to post an image.***

And the app correctly displays this (note the order of the 5 values):

***Not enough rep points to post an image.***

The RelativeLayout seemed overly bulky and I wanted to just use a simpler LinearLayout as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Player_Init"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_USGA_Index"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="IDX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Course_HCP"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="HCP" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Course"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Course" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Tees"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Tees" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Which previewed correctly in IDE as follows (note the fields are out of order from the first layout. I am about to correct):

***Not enough rep points to post an image.***

And renders properly in the app as follows:

***Not enough rep points to post an image.***

Now, when I change the order of the TextViews in the LinearLayout XML, it renders as if the wrong values are showing in the fields. Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Player_Init"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Course"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Course" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Tees"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Tees" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_USGA_Index"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="IDX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_Course_HCP"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="HCP" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the (correct) IDE preview:
***Not enough rep points to post an image.***

But, here is the app rendering:

***Not enough rep points to post an image.***
*It puts the string"ABC CC" in the right column and wraps it as if it's putting the string in the HCP field.*

Note the field order is correct but the values are somehow switched. The XML fields are rendered in the proper order, but the values of the fields are: Name, Index, Tees, HCP, Course with the value of "course" wrpped to the width of the HCP field.

No code is changed at between these examples, so it appears that the xml is causing the problems. Can anyone help me understand why? (Sorry about no images.)

Thanks.

Comment: Put in links to the images.

Comment: I love your "not enough rep points to post an image" protest. SO can be SO counterproductive sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a resource id to a UI element such as a TextView using `android:id=`, an int data field is created in the R.java file.

The R.java file can be found in the /gen directory in your project and, as with all files in this directory, it is auto-generated at build time.

Sometimes if you re-work your resource files (such as layout XML files) an int value which had previously been assigned to one resource (such as a TextView) may refer to a different resource, i.e., another TextView. This means when you use something like `findViewById(...)`, even though the R.id is referring to the UI element you want, the actual int resource id is pointing at something different.

The easiest way to fix this sort of problem is to Clean the project - this deletes any auto-generated files and re-creates them and re-builds the project.

Comment: Cleaning caused a bit of a detour, but your answer was correct. The clean seems to have straightened everything out. I don't think I ever would have found that without this forum. -- thanks.

Comment: @ddk : "I don't think I ever would have found that without this forum. " - Where do you think I found out about it? :D Glad to help.